# Where should I place my global 'gitattributes' file?

Tags: git, unix, path, gitattributes

I gather there is (despite the lack of documentation) [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2788649/656912) to set [Git attributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) globally; but I'm not clear where to place the necessary `gitattributes` file. The [instructions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) say they belong in

```
$(prefix)/etc/gitattributes
```

But where is `$(prefix)`? In particular, where would it be for OS X (with Git in `/usr/local/git/bin/git`)? Alternately (or in addition)  would `~/.gitattributes` [work](http://git.kaarsemaker.net/git/commit/2851e8eba52e98d3112417952a24d82ae9d8c0eb/)?

Comment: In a Git context, "global" usually means "user-level"; in other words, a *global* setting affect all repositories for *one* specific user.  In contrast, a *system-wide* setting affects all repositories for *all* users of a machine. Which level is of interest to you? User-level or system-wide?

Comment: @Jubobs: Both (i.e., where to put one vs. the other; there also seem to be Git-version-specific locations as well, if one has more than one Git installed, as I do); but mostly for a user.

Comment: For Windows see [Where does git config --global get written to?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2114111)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

### Global vs. system-wide settings

There is some ambiguity in your question's terminology.
In a Git context, "global" usually means "user-level"; in other words, a *global* setting affect all repositories for *one* specific user (the active one).  In contrast, a *system-wide* setting affects all repositories for *all* users of a machine.

### Repository-level gitattributes

(I'm only mentioning this for completeness.)

According to the [relevant section of the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes),

> If you wish to affect only a single repository (i.e., to assign attributes to files that are particular to one user’s workflow for that repository), then attributes should be placed in the `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` file.

`$GIT_DIR` would typically expand to `<path-to-repo-root-directory>/.git`.

### Global (user-level) gitattributes

According to the [relevant section of the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes),

> Attributes that should affect all repositories for a single user should be placed in a file specified by the `core.attributesfile` configuration option [...]. Its default value is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/attributes`. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty, `$HOME/.config/git/attributes` is used instead.

You can also run the following command,

```
git config --global core.attributesfile <path>
```

to point Git to a custom path `<path>` for your global gitattributes file, e.g. `~/.gitattributes`.

### System-wide gitattributes

According to the [relevant section of the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes),

> Attributes for all users on a system should be placed in the `$(prefix)/etc/gitattributes` file.

which naturally begs the question:

> [...] But where is `$(prefix)`?

See [What is $(prefix) on $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713622/what-is-prefix-on-prefix-etc-gitconfig) for an answer. Unless you've assigned `prefix` a custom, non-empty value, `$(prefix)` expands to nothing by default; therefore, your system-wide `gitattributes` file should reside in `/etc/`.

Comment: I have a `/usr/local/git/etc` directory which seems to be respected for `gitattributes` (at least by `/usr/local/git/bin/git`) but no `/etc/git`. There's also a `~/.config/git` directory containing an ignore that GitHub seems to have generated). It's not clear to me how all of these fit together.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius The prefix used for compiling Git during the GitHub install may have been `/usr/local/git/`; if so, `/usr/local/git/etc/gitattributes` would be your *system-wide* gitattributes; see the *System-wide gitattributes* section in my answer.  As for `~/.config/git`, that's your *global* gitattributes; see the *Global (user-level) gitattributes* section in my answer.

Comment: So (to check) any `etc` will be system wide (or at least system wide for a given Git) while the various `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/...` or `~/.configs/git/..` won't matter (for `gitignore` either) if I've set  `core.attributesfile` (or  `core.excludesfile`) to something else. E.g., if I've set it to `/.gitattributes` (*viz.* `~/.gitignore`) that's what will be used for my "global" (user-level) settings.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius If I understand you correctly, the answer is no. Repository-level settings have precedence over user-level ones, which have precedence over system-wide settings.

Comment: Yes, and repo-level supersedes those. I was checking about "globals".

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Ok. Yes.The default path for global gitattributes, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/...`, won't be used if you override it by setting a custom path with to `git config --global core.attributesfile <path>`.

Comment: Concerning `$(prefix)` note that your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713622/what-is-prefix-on-prefix-etc-gitconfig)'s answer means `prefix` is taken at _compile_ time of `git`, not at run time

Answer (score 4):

If you read this far and still don't know where `$prefix` is (i.e. it's not just  blank or `/usr/local`) or why your `/etc/gitattributes` is not being read, you can use `strace` or similar tools to see all the places git is checking. Strace prints a huge amount of debug information on stderr, so use `2>&1` and filter it, as I do below, with `grep`. The git command I chose for the example uses an attributes file because of the `--stat` which changes based on a `-diff` attribute, but any git command you are trying to run at the time should be fine.

For example, with an updated git installed on RHEL using SCL, you could end up with this:

```
$ strace -f git log --stat -1 2>&1 | grep --color 'open.*attr'
open("/opt/rh/rh-git218/root/usr/etc/gitattributes", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/username/.config/git/attributes", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open(".gitattributes", O_RDONLY)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open(".git/info/attributes", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

. . . and that shows that the $prefix here is `/opt/rh/rh-git218/root/usr`.

Strace's `-f` is not necessary here but if you don't know and don't care whether some command is going to fork, adding `-f` in the first place can eliminate a chance you won't see what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can also reference a global `.gitattribute` through new environment variables:

```
git var GIT_ATTR_GLOBAL
```

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), add more "[`git var`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89d62d5e8ef42be3a73493e8ffbede589c7a31d1/Documentation/git-var.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var))</sup> for toolsmiths to learn various locations Git is configured with either via the configuration or hardcoded defaults.

See [commit 4db16f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4db16f58c7720257eea9ffb7d4e76809f2c403f0) (27 Jun 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit ed773a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed773a18c6e92ae4f4e016f4529d6bdfbbbd56d8), [commit 576a37f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/576a37fccbf2a46d98a6dd367dbb3d1636e62f57), [commit 15780bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15780bb4f0cb07624ca6bac3c430ef07e9501663), [commit cdd489e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdd489eaf9cd3c46c30b485601e2bcb989586274), [commit f74c90d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f74c90dcf7ed8ef7994ab583de089dba2a2b1a22), [commit 1e65721](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e6572122702cbf0e3b6d3226f73e6b8b45e6e37), [commit d6546af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6546af75c3cda2815f2e4d5322dd7a41cc0963b) (27 Jun 2023) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 89d62d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89d62d5e8ef42be3a73493e8ffbede589c7a31d1), 04 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`var`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/576a37fccbf2a46d98a6dd367dbb3d1636e62f57): add attributes files locations
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> Currently, there are some programs which would like to read and parse the `gitattributes` files at the global or system levels.
> However, it's not always obvious where these files live, especially for the system file, which may have been hard-coded at compile time or computed dynamically based on the runtime prefix.
>
> It's not reasonable to expect all callers of Git to intuitively know where the Git distributor or user has configured these locations to be, so add some entries to allow us to determine their location.
> Honor the `GIT_ATTR_NOSYSTEM` environment variable if one is specified.
> Expose the accessor functions in a way that we can reuse them from within the var code.
>
> In order to make our paths consistent on Windows and also use the same form as paths use in "[`git rev-parse`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/576a37fccbf2a46d98a6dd367dbb3d1636e62f57/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse))</sup>, let's normalize the path before we return it.
> This results in Windows-style paths that use slashes, which is convenient for making our tests function in a consistent way across platforms.
> Note that this requires that some of our values be freed, so let's add a flag about whether the value needs to be freed and use it accordingly.

`git var` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/576a37fccbf2a46d98a6dd367dbb3d1636e62f57/Documentation/git-var.txt#L77-L82):

> ### `GIT_ATTR_SYSTEM`
>
> The path to the system linkgit:gitattributes[5] file, if one is enabled.
>
> ### `GIT_ATTR_GLOBAL`
>
> The path to the global (per-user) linkgit:gitattributes[5] file.