# Is there a global way to apply .gitattributes?

Tags: git, simulink, binaryfiles, gitattributes

I found a great Git function, which will unzip a file and use the uncompressed result in a diff, using .gitattributes, plus a change to your local repo config or to the global git config. This is how Simulink *.slx files are - they are zip compressed XML files, basically (maybe with some other added stuff).

However, this requires me to add a .gitattributes to every repo that needs this update - and it's config.

The particular changes needed are:

1. Add the following line to `.gitattributes`:

   ```
   *.slx diff = slx
   ```
2. Add the following lines to the local repo config (one method: `git config -e`):

   ```
   [diff "slx"]
       textconv = unzip -c -a
   ```

### Question: Is there a way to apply the same function globally to any repo through the global config file, or another method?

The goal would be that if I set up the global function locally, Git would know to uncompress any *.slx file in any repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** As [LightCC found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465606/is-there-a-global-way-to-apply-gitattributes/56465691?noredirect=1#comment99528151_56465691), you're supposed to be able to put these in your home `.git/config/attributes` or other file you set via `core.attributesFile`.  Note that any existing `.gitattributes` entry can override any settings in `core.attributesFile`.  The priority of competing entries is that those "closer to" the file override those "further away from" the file.  For instance, if the directory's `.gitattributes` says `*.ext a=b`, this overrides the top work-tree directory `.gitattributes` setting of `*.ext a=c`, which overrides `core.attributesFile` `*.ext a=d`.

<s>The short answer is no: you can define the diff textconv filter in your (personal, global-to-you) `.gitconfig` using, e.g., `git config --global -e`.  However, you must have a `.gitattributes` per-repository.</s>

It's worth adding that this idea of defining attributes in a `.gitattributes` (which has to be per-repository) but defining the drivers for them—whether they're textconv drivers for diff, merge drivers for `git merge`, or filter drivers for checkin/checkout—is a little bit broken, in my opinion at least.  The problem is that the `.gitattributes` file gets copied automatically on `git clone`, but the drivers don't.

There's a fundamental security issue that prevents Git from having the drivers copied on clone, so this *is* reasonable.  But it's clearly not a great situation.  Note that [git-lfs](/questions/tagged/git-lfs) gets around it by updating the per-repository configuration automatically; you can use the same sort of solution by running your own command, instead of `git`, that invokes Git while also fussing with your configuration.

Comment: Thanks @torek - by drivers, do you mean the `config` textconv statement?

Comment: Yes, or `[merge "foo"]`, or `[filter "foo"]`. Search [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for the word "driver".

Comment: Actually, after looking at the docs, I found there IS a global possibility (see `core.attributesfile`), but I can't get this working.  There is [an answer that goes into more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28027656/6501141). I set `core.attributesfile` to `~/.gitattributes`, and move `$repo/.gitattributes` to that location, and no conversion. Move it back into the repo, works again. Also tried `~/.config/git/attributes` location with `core.attributesfile` set to `true`.

Comment: Oh, hm, you're right. This has been in since  Git 1.7.4. It doesn't seem to work, although from a quick glance at the source, it *should* work.

Comment: It's reading the file, but something is not passing right, it appears to be getting a null string or something. This is the error I'm getting (In the Diff output from Git Extensions) - if I add a second line ("*.slx merge = slx") I get a second error with line number 2 given: `is not a valid attribute name: C:/Users/210068178/.gitattributes:1`
`is not a valid attribute name: C:/Users/210068178/.gitattributes:2`

Comment: Okay, got it working - make sure you don't put spaces around the equals sign in your attribute definitions... `*.slx diff = slx` does not work, it must be `*.slx diff=slx`.  Which means I had something else different broken the time I literally copied the working file from the repo...